# Android choose your app among possibilities to attach image to SMS/MMS message

Tags: android, image, attachment

I have troubles finding information what to do in order to achieve:

1. User is texting a message
2. Clicks attachment to add image
3. Your app is also displayed among other possibilities

Should I add anything to my Main activity or manifest??

**EDIT**: Solution in answer below.

How to return chosen image from app back to sms/mms?

My code starts share action again so you need to enter receiver again which is not optimal:

```
 public class StartActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



Intent myIntent = getIntent();
final int image = myIntent.getExtras().getInt("image");

ImageView imagefull = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imagefull.setImageResource(image);




Button share = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonshare);
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 

{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        OutputStream output;    

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        image);

        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Shared Movie Quotes/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(dir, "quote.png");

        try {

            // Share Intent
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            // Type of file to share
            share.setType("image/jpeg");

            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            // Locate the image to Share
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Pass the image into an Intnet
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            // Show the social share chooser list
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Let them know!"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    } );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android intent filter: add attachment to SMS/MMS message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493867/android-intent-filter-add-attachment-to-sms-mms-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding below intent filter:

```
    <activity android:name="YourActivity">
        <!-- filter for showing when image is selected -->
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

Comment: This works now..
Any idea how would I return chosen image to sms/mms message?

Comment: I added correct "action" for intent and updated the answer.                  Select your app from the list/dialog that is shown,
 and Once you choose an image from your "app", control will come back to SMS App with selected image attached.